# Subset a list of strings by the first word

Tags: r, string, list

Is it possible to subset a list of strings e.g. List[1:3] using grepl? I want to identify the first word in a character string to begin the index and end the index with the first word of the string that matches.

The reason I don't want to use the numeric index is that I plan on subsetting multiple financial statement pdfs and they may differ in terms of what is contained in the list.

Here is the data I have:

```
list(c("CASH $99,999,999.00 $99,999,999.00 0.00"), 
    c("CASH SLIPS 1,000,000.00 1,000,000.00 0.00"), 
    c("BONDS 500,000.00 (500,000.00)"), 
    c("ACCOUNTS RECEIVABLE 1,000,000.00 2,000,000.00 (1,000,000.00)"))
```

How would I subset by beginning at CASH i.e. the exact match, not CASH SLIPS, and end at BONDS?

Desired output:

```
list(c("CASH $99,999,999.00 $99,999,999.00 0.00"), 
        c("CASH SLIPS 1,000,000.00 1,000,000.00 0.00"), 
        c("BONDS 500,000.00 (500,000.00)"))
```

Comment: Your desired list shows `CASH SLIPS` while description is `. the exact match, not CASH SLIPS,`

Comment: When I was trying to use reply I noticed that it was matching both CASH and CASH SLIPS. So your answer is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `Filter` from `base R`

```
Filter(function(x) grepl("^(CASH|BONDS)", x), lst1)
#[[1]]
#[1] "CASH $99,999,999.00 $99,999,999.00 0.00"

#[[2]]
#[1] "CASH SLIPS 1,000,000.00 1,000,000.00 0.00"

#[[3]]
#[1] "BONDS 500,000.00 (500,000.00)"
```

---

Or another option if we want to subset based on the starting index of 'CASH' and ending index of 'BONDS'

```
i1 <- sub("\\s+[^A-Z]+", "", unlist(lst1)) %in% c("CASH", "BONDS")
lst1[Reduce(`:`, as.list(range(which(i1))))]
#[[1]]
#[1] "CASH $99,999,999.00 $99,999,999.00 0.00"

#[[2]]
#[1] "CASH SLIPS 1,000,000.00 1,000,000.00 0.00"

#[[3]]
#[1] "BONDS 500,000.00 (500,000.00)"
```

---

Or using `grepl`

```
lst1[Reduce(`:`, as.list(range(grep("^(CASH|BONDS)\\s+([^A-Z])", unlist(lst1)))))]
#[[1]]
#[1] "CASH $99,999,999.00 $99,999,999.00 0.00"

#[[2]]
#[1] "CASH SLIPS 1,000,000.00 1,000,000.00 0.00"

#[[3]]
#[1] "BONDS 500,000.00 (500,000.00)"
```

---

or using `keep` from `purrr`

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
keep(lst1, ~ str_detect(.x, '^(CASH|BONDS)'))
```

---

Or with `sapply` and `word`

```
lst1[sapply(lst1, word, 1) %in% c("CASH", "BONDS")]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the words until a number or `"$"` sign is encountered for each list.

```
first_word <- sapply(data, function(x) sub('(.*?)\\s(\\d+|\\$).*', '\\1', x))
first_word
#[1] "CASH"    "CASH SLIPS"     "BONDS"    "ACCOUNTS RECEIVABLE"
```

and use these `first_word` to select elements from the list which start with `"CASH"` and end at `"BONDS"`.

```
data[which(first_word == 'CASH'):which(first_word == 'BONDS')]

#[[1]]
#[1] "CASH $99,999,999.00 $99,999,999.00 0.00"

#[[2]]
#[1] "CASH SLIPS 1,000,000.00 1,000,000.00 0.00"

#[[3]]
#[1] "BONDS 500,000.00 (500,000.00)"
```